# How do I send Data between Activities without using Intents?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 Activities, the 1st Activity starts the 2nd one with an Intent. The 2nd Activity has a ListView. When I click on a ListItem, I want to send the 1st Activity the position(int) if the item I clicked on and then finish() the 2nd Activity. However I cant use Intent.putExtra because I dont want to start the 1st Activity again. So the Question is: How do I send Data between Activities without Intents? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand you asked how to **not** use an `Intent` and the target answer uses them. But that is how you would do it using an `Intent` (which is actually what you need to do) and it **won't** restart the first Activity.

Comment: By using `startActivityForResult`, for more info check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/5723787) thread

Comment: Yep that works, didnt know about that! Thank you guys!